# How to wait on a refresh of a classic report region before checking the length of the report?

Tags: javascript, refresh, oracle-apex

Im using 18.2.0.00.12 ,  the default oracle apex client they provide for free.

My issue is that my classic report region is refreshing after I make a dynamic check for the length of the report.
My main page is a classic report with a list of values.  There is a button to add a value in a modal dialog.  After the element is added in the modal, the modal closes and a dynamic action is triggered on my main page to refresh the report  (this is working).  My issue is that after I refresh the report,  I make another Javascript call (see below) in order to check the length of the report.  Based on the result, it either shows/hides a button.

```
if ($('#report_RC_ATTACH').length > 0) 
{
$('#DELETE_ATTACH').show(); 
} else 
{
$('#DELETE_ATTACH').hide(); 
}
```

The Static ID for my region is RC_ATTACH.  The static region for my button is DELETE_ATTACH.  Also note,  after the dynamic action finishes, I am able to go into the console, put in the code above and the button show/hides correctly.  I think the issue is that the region is refreshed after the code above is called.

My question:  Is there a way to delay or wait until the refresh occurs before making the length check?

Let me know if I can provide anymore information.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a classic report you need to wait for the **apexafterrefresh** event to trigger. You can create a dynamic action with the framework event **After Refresh** that waits for this event and place your code there. Refer to the documentation [About Dynamic Action Events](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/managing-dynamic-actions.htm) for details.

Comment: That sounds right, thank you! Ill try it out soon and mark your answer correct.